# restore sudo privilege without knowing sudo account

Tags: permissions, root, restore

I always access to a test server using an account. But I has done some mess and now the user is no more a root user. I can restore privileges without knowing root credential? How can i solve (at last I can ask after the holidays week).

Comment: If local to the machine, try using GRUB's "recovery mode" option(s) to reach a root shell.